# Auto increment strange behavior in mysql - any reason for this?

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

I have a regular auto-increment column for site member accounts. I noticed that after it got to account number 545, the increment number jumped to 333333333, and has been counting from there since when creating new accounts.

I guess it's not a massive problem, but any idea why would it do this?

Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: If you insert a row with autoincrement column value far from the current value - it will continue counting.

Comment: either you had 333332788 failed registrations causing that many rollbacks and abandoned IDs, or you imported a dump that had the table's auto_increment value set that high. No way to tell.

Comment: If you insert records and then delete them, the auto_increment keeps counting where it was.

Comment: Make sure there is no TRIGGER on this table.

Comment: Thanks for your replies guys. There are no other signs of failed and rolled back registrations, an there was no import. No triggers set. I'll keep an eye on it to see if it happens again and leaves more clues.